# How can I search and replace, using regex, within the results of a previous search?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, replace, jscript

Thanks for taking the time to read this and apologies right off the bat if this is slightly confusing, remedial or has been previously asked (extensive searching, limited results).

I'm editing using archaic software, HomeSite 5 if you're familiar, and it allows the use of scripts.

**My conundrum is as follows:**

> I would like to isolate multiple selections of text. I am currently doing this using a (long-winded) regex that captures all of the content following a <s>certain</s>specifically set date (in this instance "2030-12-31") until it reaches a certain tag (in this instance `]]<content>`). Thus far I have managed.
>
> I then would like, within only those previously found selections of text, to remove all of the `<span>` tags it contains. However, I would like the `<span>` tags in other sections of text to remain (for example those assigned earlier dates).

Individually I can carry-out both functions, isolating the specific sections or removing all of the `<span>` tags, I feel there's just a link that I'm not aware of that can enable me to run one within the other.

Once again, apologies if the answer is very simple; my knowledge of scripting and regex is limited at best. I've been doing most of my work using Jscript, however I'm not certain if HomeSite accepts other formats - I'm open to multiple solutions!

> **TLDR:** Search and replace only within certain selections, as specified by immediately preceeding regex.

**EDIT 1**:
Please see below the expression used to isolate the required sections. The first is the entire expression. The second is the container in which the content is captured.:

```
/<version recordId="([0-9]{4,})" start="2030-12-31"([^>]*)>([^<]*)<title><!\[CDATA\[<span class="uk">([^<]*)<\/span>\]\]><\/title>([^<]*)<number><!\[CDATA\[<span class="uk">([0-9]{1,3})\.<\/span>\]\]><\/number>([^<]*)<content><!\[CDATA\[([^]]*)\]\]><\/content>([^<]*)<\/version>/g;

..<content><!\[CDATA\[([^]]*)\]\]></content>..
```

Within that I would hop to amend as follows:

```
<span class="uk">content</span>
content
```

Now that I've typed that out in public I am aware what kind of a horror show of a regular expression it is and I apologise to the good coders of stackoverflow for even having to look at it!

**EDIT 2**:
Please see below an example of desired output:

```
<version recordId="1234" start="2012-01-01"><stuffhere...<content><![CDATA[[
  <span class="uk">content1</span>
  <span class="uk">content2</span>
 ]]</content>
    </version>
 <version record="4231" start="2030-12-31"><stuffhere...<content><![CDATA[[
   <span class="uk">content1</span>
   <span class="uk">content2</span>
 ]]</content>
    </version>
```

**BECOMES**

```
<version recordId="1234" start="2012-01-01"><stuffhere...<content><![CDATA[[
  <span class="uk">content1</span>
  <span class="uk">content2</span>
 ]]</content>
    </version>
 <version record="4231" start="2030-12-31"><stuffhere...<content><![CDATA[[
   content1
   content2
 ]]</content>
    </version>
```

n.b: Thanks to Hannele for earlier formatting corrections.

Comment: Can you give some sample input, desired output and the regexes you already have?

Comment: `following a certain date`: regex aren't powerfull enough for this kind of job. You could at worst match exactly a date like you've tried, but you won't be able to match *youngest* dates. Will it still suit your needs?

Comment: @sp00m, thanks for looking through the question. Apologies if it isn't at all clear in the above wall of text: the date assigned to the content I wish to edit will always be 'start="2030-12-31"'. I haven't had any trouble with that RegEx, albeit long, picking up the correct sections. The trouble starts when I want to edit content within only those sections. Sections dated differently, i.e, 'start="2012-01-01"' or 'start="1998-29-02"' will be ignored. Thanks again, mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using a callback function with `String.replace()`

The second argument to the `String.replace()` method, (the replacement text), may be specified as a callback function. This callback function can in turn have another `replace()` call. In this manner, you can easily process text-within-a-section. Here is an example that demonstrates this technique.

Given this example text:

### Before:

`blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.`
`<section1>blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.</section1>`
`blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.`
`<section2>blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.</section2>`
`blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.`

Let's say you want to replace each `foo` with `bar`, but only within the sections. This is easily done by using a callback function as the replacement argument of the `String.replace()` method like so:

```js
function f1(text) {
    var re1 = /<section(\d+)>[\S\s]*?<\/section\1>/g;
    var re2 = /foo/ig;
    text = text.replace(re1,
        function(m0, m1){
            return m0.replace(re2, 'bar');
        });
    return text;
}
```

When a pattern match is found, the `replace()` method calls the callback function and passes the whole match in the first argument (in the above example I named it: `"m0"`). If the regex has capture groups, the matched text for each of these groups are passed in following arguments (in this case, there is only one capture group, and I've named this argument: `"m1"` - and note that this argument is not used by the function).

Here is the example text after being processed by the above function:

### After:

`blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.`
`<section1>blah bar? bar blah bar, bar.</section1>`
`blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.`
`<section2>blah bar? bar blah bar, bar.</section2>`
`blah foo? foo blah foo, foo.`

Comment: Thank you very much, @ridgerunner, for a quite elegant solution. Succinct and effective, I knew there would be a technique I wasn't aware of, and I've now taken 'functions within replace' over to other scripts and found improvements.  Once again, thanks.